# ArangoDB: limit at 10 documents in graph

Tags: graph, arangodb, limits

I have created a Graph in ArangoDB and I want to use it with 15 Collections, but the GUI tells me that:

> You can only select 10 items

for each n-tuple (`fromCollections, toCollections, EdgeDefinitions`).

What can I do to go over the limit?

Thank you.

Daniele

Comment: Did the answer work for you? if yes, can you mark it 'accepted'? If not, whats missing?

Comment: That's fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AQL currently has a limit of 32 collections useable in one query. You can create graphs like this in arangosh:

```
var Graph = require("org/arangodb/general-graph");
```

A graph with 15 edge collections:

```
var g = Graph._create("test1",
  [
    Graph._relation("edge_1", "test", "test"),
    ...
    Graph._relation("edge_15", "test", "test")
  ]
);
```

And another one with 34 edge collections (thats 35 collections combined with the one vertex collection):

```
var g = Graph._create("test2",
  [
    Graph._relation("edge_1", "test", "test"),
    ...
    Graph._relation("edge_34", "test", "test")
  ]
);
```

We save a dummy start node for a traversal:

```
db.test.save({_key: 'a'})
```

if you now query test1, you will get the expected empty result (we don't have any edges):

```
db._query("FOR v IN 1..1 ANY 'test/a' GRAPH 'test1' RETURN v")
```

But if you query test2, you will get:

```
ArangoError: too many collections (while parsing)
```

You may work on the test2 graph using the [edgeCollectionRestriction option of the `GRAPH_*` functions](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.8/Aql/GraphOperations.html) to select a subset of the 34 collections configured.

While the webui may be a nice thing for simple tasks, I don't think its useable to achieve creation of tasks like presented above.